# setting state in react with nested .map functions possible?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am developing a simple multiple choice question and answer app using react component functions.

Each question has 2 or 4 possible answers where I have the data configured in nested objects / arrays an example is like below:

```
{
question: 'what country is....',
id: nanoid(),
answers: 
[{
  answer: 'Egypt',
  id: nanoid(),
  isCorrect: true,
  isChecked: false
},
{
  answer: 'Greece',
  id: nanoid(),
  isCorrect: false,
  isChecked: false
},
{......}
```

my problem is when I want to flip the 'isChecked' attribute (when someone clicks on the corresponding button) I need to iterate through the object and then iterate through the 'answers' array, however I am unable to set state correctly, I tried nested map methods, I also am trying nested for loops, but I just can't get the desired results no matter what I try.

What is a simple method when having nested objects and arrays to setState correctly and reliably?

here is my code below

App.js

```
import React from 'react'
import Questions from './Questions'
import { nanoid } from 'nanoid'
import { decode } from 'he'

export default function App() {
  const [tempState, setTempState] = React.useState(true)
  const [data, setData] = React.useState([])


  React.useEffect(() => {
    fetch("https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=5&category=9&difficulty=medium")
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(info => stateFormat(info.results))
  }, [])


  function stateFormat(rawData) {
    // console.log(rawData)
    let correctAnswers = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < rawData.length; i++) {
      correctAnswers.push({
        question: rawData[i].question,
        id: nanoid(),
        answers: [{
          answer: rawData[i].correct_answer,
          id: nanoid(),
          isCorrect: true,
          isChecked: false
        }]
      })
      if (rawData[i].incorrect_answers.length > 2) {
        for (let j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
          correctAnswers[i].answers.push({
            answer: rawData[i].incorrect_answers[j],
            id: nanoid(),
            isCorrect: false,
            isChecked: false
          })
        }
      } else {
        correctAnswers[i].answers.push({
          answer: rawData[i].incorrect_answers[0],
          id: nanoid(),
          isCorrect: false,
          isChecked: false
        })
      }
    }
    setData(correctAnswers)
    console.log(data)

  }


  function handleChange(id) {
    setData(prev => {
      for(let i = 0; i < prev.length; i++) {
        for(let j = 0; j < prev[i].answers.length; j++) {
          // console.log(prev[i].answers[j])

          if(prev[i].answers[j].id === id) {
              console.log({...prev[i].answers[j], isChecked: !prev[i].answers[j].isChecked})
              return {...prev[i].answers[j], isChecked: !prev[i].answers[j].isChecked}
          } else {
            // return {...prev[i].answers[j]}
          }
        }
      }
    })
      
      
    
  }


  // function handleChange(id) {
  //   setData(prev => prev.map(item => {
  //    return (item.answers.map(button => {
  //       return button.id === id ?
  //       { ...button, isChecked: !button.isChecked } :
  //       button
  //     }))
      
  //   }))
  // }


  const questionElements = data.map(item => (
    <Questions
      key={item.id}
      question={item.question}
      answers={item.answers}
      handleChange={handleChange}
    />
  ))




  return (
    <main>
      <img className="blob--top"
        src={require('./blobs.png')}
      />
      <img className="blob--bottom"
        src={require('./blobs1.png')}
      />
      {tempState ?

        <div className="quiz--container">
          <div>
            {questionElements}
            <button className="game--check button">Check answers</button>
          </div>

        </div> :
        <>
          <div className="title--container">
            <div className="title--init">
              <h2 className="title--header">Quizzical</h2>
              <h4 className="title--subheader">A battle of the brains</h4>
              <button className="game--start button"
                onClick={() => setTempState(!tempState)}
              >
                Start quiz</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </>
      }
    </main>
  );
}
```

Questions.js

```
import React from 'react'
import { decode } from 'he'

export default function Questions(props) {
 

    // console.log(props)

    const answerButton = props.answers.map(item => (
        <button
            isCorrect={item.isCorrect}
            isChecked={item.isChecked}
            id={item.id}
            style={{backgroundColor: item.isChecked ? "#D6DBF5" : ""}}
            onClick={() => props.handleChange(item.id)}>{decode(item.answer)}
        </button>
    ))

    return (
        <div className="question--container">
            <h4>{decode(props.question)}</h4>
            <div className="question--items">
                {answerButton}
            </div>
            <img src={require('./Line13.png')} />
        </div>

    )

}
```

the issue is with my handleChange(id) function, what can be done to return the appropriate object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `.map()` approach is very close, you just need to wrap your inner `.map()` in an object. The object should contain all the `item` properties, which you can create by spreading the current `item` with `...item`, and then overwrite the `answer` property to be your mapped `answers` array:

```js
function handleChange(id) {
  setData(prev => prev.map(item => {
    return {
      ...item,
      answers: item.answers.map(button => {
        return button.id === id
          ? { ...button, isChecked: !button.isChecked} 
          : button
      })
    };
  }));
}
```

With arrow functions, you can omit the function body `{}` and hence the `return` if all you're doing is returning from within the body. So the above can be rewritten as:

```js
function handleChange(id) {
  setData(prev => prev.map(item => ({
    ...item,
    answers: item.answers.map(button => button.id === id
      ? { ...button, isChecked: !button.isChecked} 
      : button
    )
  })));
}
```

---

Note that if you want to make your code more efficient, you can also pass the question `id` when you call `handleChange()`, which will allow you to add an additional condition in your outer `.map()` so that you only perform your inner `.map()` when you're iterated the question being answered, for all the other questions you can then skip the inner `.map()` iteration on the `answers` array as you know these haven't changed.